# What is the character count limitation for os commands on colab python? (OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have to rename 100s of generated files based on some strings as part of a Google Colaboratory script. Its a simple os.rename as follows:

`os.rename(‘path1’, ‘path2’)`

The script throws the following error for one renaming operation:

`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'path1' -> 'path2'`

`path1` and `path2` have **54** and **303** characters respectively. Do these character counts exceed the limit? Is that all the issue is? If so, what are the limits on character count when using python on colab and os.XXXX operations? Both the paths have no special characters, just alphanumeric and spaces.

Comment: Is your 303-character `path2` just a filename (255 is generally the limit for that), or a pathname with multiple directory levels (4096 is a common limit for that)?

Comment: The filename alone is 260 characters. These limits are with python/gdrive file names/colab/OS?